# fifo から read するスクリプトの挙動が、 OS 間で異なっている理由がわからない

Tags: sh, unix

次のような、名前付きパイプ(fifo) を利用するスクリプトを記述しました。

```
#!/bin/sh

set -ex

rm -rf fifo
mkfifo fifo

cat <<EOF > fifo &
hoge
fuga
moge
EOF

while read -r line < fifo
do
    echo $line
done

echo "EOF!"
```

これを、 Mac OS X で実行した時には、途中で処理が止まってしまいます。 (Ctrl+C で中止している)

```
$ ./test-fifo.sh
+ rm -rf fifo
+ mkfifo fifo
+ read -r line
+ cat
+ echo hoge
hoge
+ read -r line
^C
```

一方、 ubuntu(14.04, dash0.5.7) 上で実行した場合には、意図通りにスクリプトは実行できています。

```
$ ./test-fifo.sh 
+ rm -rf fifo
+ mkfifo fifo
+ read -r line
+ cat
+ echo hoge
hoge
+ read -r line
+ echo fuga
fuga
+ read -r line
+ echo moge
moge
+ read -r line
+ echo EOF!
EOF!
```

質問:

- どうして、このような OS 間の挙動の差異が発生するのでしょうか。

仮説(考えたこと)

1. このスクリプトの挙動はそもそも undefined である。

   - ただ、だとするとその旨の記述はどこかに仕様として記述があるのでは、と考えていて、それが見つけられないと考えている状態です。
2. OS 間で fifo の挙動が、仕様として差異がある。

   - この場合も同様に、その仕様がどこかにまとまっていると考えていますが、それをどうやったら探せるのかわからないと思っている状態です。

---

追記@ 2016/04/03

手元の ubuntu 環境(14.04) だと、 bash でも dash でも、同じようによろしく動いてしまっています。。

bash

```
$ bash test-fifo.sh 
+ rm -rf fifo
+ mkfifo fifo
+ read -r line
+ cat
+ echo hoge
hoge
+ read -r line
+ echo fuga
fuga
+ read -r line
+ echo moge
moge
+ read -r line
+ echo 'EOF!'
EOF!
```

dash

```
$ dash test-fifo.sh 
+ rm -rf fifo
+ mkfifo fifo
+ read -r line
+ cat
+ echo hoge
hoge
+ read -r line
+ echo fuga
fuga
+ read -r line
+ echo moge
moge
+ read -r line
+ echo EOF!
EOF!
```

---

自分の手元の、よろしく動いてしまう ubuntu で、 dash/bash の `strace` を見る限りは、次のような動作をしていました。

1. `hoge\nfuga\nmoge` を cat するプロセスが、この文字列を fifo に write する。 write システムコールが発行されて、このプロセスの実行がしばらく止まる。
2. シェルが１文字ずつ read する。 `hoge\n` になったら fifo を close する。
3. シェルが echo 処理を行う
4. シェルが再び fifo をオープンして、 手順の 2 に戻る
5. 2-4 を繰り返して、`hoge\nfuga\nmoge\n`がなくなると、 cat プロセスに実行が戻る。 cat プロセスが正常終了する。
6. read で何も読み込めなかったので、 while のループを抜ける。その後正常終了する。

プロセスの実行タイミングと、 fifo の fd の open/close のタイミングの問題な気がしてきています。

Comment: こちらの環境(`Ubuntu 16.04`, `dash 0.5.8`(`/bin/sh` の実体))だと、`hoge` が出力された後、`cannot open fifo: Interrupted system call` と表示されて異常終了します。なお、`while read -r line < fifo; do ...` とすると `fifo` を複数回 `open/close` する事になってしまうので(`fifo` に対する `open for write` と `open for read` は同じ回数にする必要があります)、`while read -r line;do echo $line; done < fifo` とすべきでしょうね。

Comment: @argus その、 # open for write == # open for read であるべきという仕様は、どこかに書いてあるものでしょうか？( man mkfifo 2 とかをみてみたら、かいてあるのかなと思っている状態です

Comment: 直接的な記述ではありませんが、POSIX.1 の http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html に、`When all file descriptors associated with a pipe or FIFO special file are closed, any data remaining in the pipe or FIFO shall be discarded.` という記述があります。なので、一度に複数行を `fifo` に書き込んだ場合、`read -r line < fifo` とすると 2 行目以降は破棄される事になります。

Comment: @argus そうなのでしょうか。パッと見た感じだと、その記述は、「紐付いている fd がすべて閉じられてしまったら、内容を破棄する」 であって、プロセス内に限らずシステム上で開いている fd があれば破棄されない、のではないかと思っています。何か自分は解釈間違えてたりするのでしょうか。。

Comment: @argus ああ、そうか。「複数行書き込む」「書き込み終了(close)」「一行読み込む」「読み込み終了(close)」すれば、確かにこのうまくいってない方の挙動が説明できますね。ただ、そうするとまた疑問なのが、fifo って書き込んでいる内容が読み込まれるまでは、書き込み側がブロックする、という挙動だったような気がしてるのですが、そうではないということなのでしょうか…？

Comment: fifo はほどよくパイプ内容をバッファリングできるんですかね？そうするとすべて説明できそうな気がしてきた。

Comment: Linux で `strace` を使って動作を追ってみると、`dash` と `bash` では挙動が異なっています。`bash` では最初の `read` の後で `cat` プロセスの終了を待っているのですが、`dash` では待たずに2回めの `read` を実行しています。なので、`dash` で `while read -r line < fifo && wait` などとすると `bash` と同じ結果になります(実際には意味のないコードですが…)。

Comment: OSによるのfifloの挙動の違いではなく、シェルによるreadコマンドの挙動の違いだったという事ですね。

Comment: @mjy bash と dash, 両方を実行してみましたが、自分の手元だと、動作はやっぱり変わってないです。。(質問に追記します)

Comment: なるほど。自分も試してみました。結果は3通りあり、1. 無事最後まで実行される 2.ブロック状態で停止する 2. @argus さんの最初のコメントのようにエラーを吐く 、です。どうなるかは運しだいでした。少し考えてみます。

Comment: @argus 質問に、手元の ubuntu  の strace 上の挙動を追記しました。ところで、 `bash` は最初の `read`の後に `cat` の終了を待っているということですが、 `wait` システムコールを(2回目の read の前に) `bash` が実行しているということですか？ (それは、自分の bash の理解に反する挙動なので、この質問をしています)

Comment: `strace` の結果を回答欄に載せました。

Comment: @argus なるほど、 cat が exit してるために、 bash のシグナルハンドラが呼ばれて、そこで wait してるのですね、理解しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

仕様が欲しいとこの質問を開始しましたが、調べていくうちにそんなものはないのでは、と思うようになったので、それをまとめておきます。

観測されている(話し合われている)挙動は、３通りあって、並列実行されるプロセスの、タイミングの問題であるのではないか、と思っています。

1. fifo が cat と bash のプロセスで開かれる
2. cat が fifo に write する

   - この直後に cat 側で close された場合には、1回目の read の後に close されて、 紐づく fd がなくなるので fifo が初期化される -> ２回目の read が block される (自分の mac ・ argus さんの dash で観測した事象)
3. bash: read 1 回目: `hoge\n` を読み込む
4. bash 側で fifo が close される

   - この直後に cat 側で close された場合には、2回目 fifo open のシステムコールの最初にソフト割り込みの判定が行われてるっぽくて、そこで `Interrupted system call` (argus さんの dash で観測された事象)
5. cat 側の close が最後まで行われなければ、問題なくこのスクリプトは動作する (自分の ubuntu で観測した事象)

---

この仮説があっているとすると、自分の当初の質問に対する答えは、 1. このスクリプトの動作は 非決定的, 理由は、プロセスの並列実行のタイミングの問題のため。

Comment: タイミングの問題という事で正しいと思います。`cat`が`write`, `close`を行なう時、シェルが(`read`で) `fifo`を開いて待機していないとマズい事になりますね。このコードだとechoとかしている事がありえます。 `write`はこのコードだと最初の一回だけでしょうから、これは`fifo`によって自動でタイミングが合います。問題は次ですね。次の`close`までにキャッシュに貯まった3行を読み切って再び`fifo`を`open`して待機できればセーフ、という感じでしょうか。極端に遅い`cat`を使えば確実に成功させる事が出来ます。（`Interrupted system call`は自分の環境では殆ど再現出来なかった事もあり、まだなぜ起こるのか理解できていません。）

Comment: @mjy Interrupted system call について、仮設なんですけど、 fifo が閉じられた時点で、ソフトウェア割り込みのキューに、 fifo を綺麗にする処理が積まれるのではないか、と考えています。 open (に限らず、大体のシステムコール) は、ソフト割り込みがあっても正しく動作するために、最初に割り込みの確認を行うと。 open しようとしたファイルが、まさに、そのファイルを clean する割り込み処理が積まれていれば、システムコールとして interrupted で戻ってきてもおかしくはないかなぁ、と。

Answer (score 1):

以下は `dash` と `bash` の `strace` の結果なので回答ではないのですが、コメント欄には収まらないので回答欄を使います。

環境は `Ubuntu 16.04, Linux kernel 4.4.0, dash 0.5.8, bash 4.3.42` です。

**dash**

```
$ strace -f ./test-fifo.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

ここで、`pid 8095` が `cat` プロセス、`8092` が `dash` プロセスです。

# 適当に端折っています

```
getpid()              = 8092
[pid  8095] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat"], [/* 65 vars */]) = 0

# Write to FIFO
[pid  8095] read(0, "hoge\nfuga\nmoge\n", 131072) = 15
[pid  8095] write(1, "hoge\nfuga\nmoge\n", 15 <unfinished ...>

# Read from FIFO
[pid  8092] open("fifo", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE <unfinished ...>
[pid  8092] <... read resumed> "h", 1) = 1
[pid  8092] <... read resumed> "o", 1) = 1
[pid  8092] <... read resumed> "g", 1) = 1
[pid  8092] <... read resumed> "e", 1) = 1
[pid  8092] read(0, "\n", 1) = 1

# Next read
[pid  8092] write(1, "hoge\n", 5) = 5
[pid  8092] open("fifo", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE <unfinished ...>
[pid  8095] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=8095, si_uid=1000, ...
write(2, "cannot open fifo: Interrupted sy"..., 41cannot open fifo: Interrupted system call) = 41
```

**bash**

`pid 8495` が `cat` プロセス、`8492` が `bash` プロセスです。1回目の read の直後からになります。

```
[pid  8492] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
[pid  8495] +++ exited with 0 +++
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=8495, si_uid=1000, ...
waitpid(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG) = 8495
waitpid(-1, 0xbfe8f374, WNOHANG)        = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
sigreturn({mask=[]})                    = 0
write(1, "hoge\n", 5)                   = 5
open("fifo", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
```