# bashでコマンドの標準入力にEOFを明示的に書き込む方法

Tags: bash

bashのシェルスクリプトのなかで実行されるコマンドにEOFを明示的に渡す方法はあるでしょうか。
具体的にやりたいことは以下になります。
何卒よろしくお願いします。

---

以下のようなシェルスクリプト `test.sh` と2つのテキストファイル `txt1.txt` `txt2.txt` があります。

- *test.sh*

  ```sh
  #! /bin/bash
  echo "========="
  cat 
  echo "========="
  cat 
  echo "========="
  ```
- *txt1.txt*

  ```
  test1
  test2
  ```
- *txt2.txt*

  ```
  test3
  test4
  ```

このスクリプトをターミナルで以下のように実行すると、出力は以下のようになります。

*ターミナル:*

```
$ cat txt1.txt txt2.txt | ./test.sh
=========
test1
test2
test3
test4
=========
=========
```

シェルスクリプトには手を加えずに、ターミナルでのコマンド実行により以下の出力を得る方法を探しています。

```
$ ???????
=========
test1
test2
=========
test3
test4
=========
```

Comment: 「シェルスクリプトには手を加えずに」という制限は何故なのでしょうか？

Comment: 特に意味はありません。この質問自体、具体的な必要性があってのことではなくbashの勉強中に行き当たった疑問を投稿した次第です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> #! /bin/bash
> echo "========="
> cat 
> echo "========="
> cat 
> echo "========="
> ```

このスクリプトでは、最初の`cat`でEOFが検出された後、次の`cat`でも即座にEOFが検出されるので、スクリプトを修正しないと要望されていることはできないと思います。

Comment: そこんところは全く同意なのですが `cat - hoge.txt -` はコンソール相手だと２回読んでくれるんですよね。 `cat` が中で `freopen` してるという。 `cat hoge | cat - -` は無理。

Comment: GNU `cat`(1) 調べですが `strace` や `ltrace` などで `cat` のプロセスをトレースするとわかりますが、`freopen` はしていませんよ。

Comment: GNU coreutil-8.20 の `cat` のソースは `freopen` しているみたいっす。 `xfreopen(NULL, "rb", stdin);` とかあります。

Comment: mkfifo で FIFO を作って `dd if=/dev/null of=fifo oflag=nocache conv=sync` を EOF 替わりにするなんて事してみたのですけれど、上手く行かない環境があってよく分からない状態。

Comment: 不可能、とのことで納得しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

既に解決？済みなので参考までに。

承認済回答のコメント欄に書きましたが、FIFO(named pipe) を使います。

**fake_eof.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 2>/dev/null
./test.sh < fifo &
cat txt1.txt > fifo
dd if=/dev/null of=fifo bs=1 count=1
cat txt2.txt > fifo
```

FIFO ファイルを作成して(`mkfifo fifo`)、`./fake_eof.sh` を実行すると、**環境によっては**質問欄にある様な出力になります。要は FIFO(named pipe) に対する read/write のタイミング次第ですので、同じ環境でも実行毎に結果が異なる場合もあり得ます。

この「FIFO に対する read/write のタイミング」については(興味があれば)[こちらの質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/23686/)を参照して見て下さい。また、[Pipes and FIFOs (The GNU C Library)](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipes-and-FIFOs.html) も参考になるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。大変勉強になりました。